# Avoid initial scrolling when using Jetpack Compose ScrollableTabRow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tabs

I'm using a `ScrollableTabRow` to display some 60 Tabs.
At the very beginning, the indicator should start "in the middle".
However, this results in an unwanted scrolling animation when the composable is drawn - see video. Am i doing something wrong or is this component buggy?

[image]

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun MinimalTabExample() {
    val tabCount = 60
    var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(tabCount / 2) }

    ScrollableTabRow(selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex) {
        repeat(tabCount) { tabNumber ->
            Tab(
                selected = selectedTabIndex == tabNumber,
                onClick = { selectedTabIndex = tabNumber },
                text = { Text(text = "Tab #$tabNumber") }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**But why would you like to do that?**
I'm writing a calendar-like application and have a day-detail-view.
From there want a fast way to navigate to adjacent days. A Month into the future and a month into the past - relative to the selected month - is what i'm aiming for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you are not doing it wrong. Also the component is not really buggy, rather the behaviour you are seeing is an implementation detail.

If we check the implementation of the `ScrollableTabRow` composable we see that the `selectedTabIndex` is used in two places inside the composable:

1. inside the default indicator implementation
2. as an input parameter for the `scrollableTableData.onLaidOut` call

The #1 is used for positioning the tabs inside the layout, so it is not interesting for this issue.

The #2 is used to scroll to the selected tab index.
The code below shows how the initial scroll state is set up, followed by the call to `scrollableTabData.onLaidOut`

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val scrollableTabData = remember(scrollState, coroutineScope) {
    ScrollableTabData(
        scrollState = scrollState,
        coroutineScope = coroutineScope
    )
}

// ...

scrollableTabData.onLaidOut(
    density = this@SubcomposeLayout,
    edgeOffset = padding,
    tabPositions = tabPositions,
    selectedTab = selectedTabIndex // <-- selectedTabIndex is passed here
)
```

And this is the implementation of the above call

```
    fun onLaidOut(
        density: Density,
        edgeOffset: Int,
        tabPositions: List<TabPosition>,
        selectedTab: Int
    ) {
        // Animate if the new tab is different from the old tab, or this is called for the first
        // time (i.e selectedTab is `null`).
        if (this.selectedTab != selectedTab) {
            this.selectedTab = selectedTab
            tabPositions.getOrNull(selectedTab)?.let {
                // Scrolls to the tab with [tabPosition], trying to place it in the center of the
                // screen or as close to the center as possible.
                val calculatedOffset = it.calculateTabOffset(density, edgeOffset, tabPositions)
                if (scrollState.value != calculatedOffset) {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        scrollState.animateScrollTo( // <-- even the initial scroll is done using an animation
                            calculatedOffset,
                            animationSpec = ScrollableTabRowScrollSpec
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As we can see already from the first comment

> Animate if the new tab is different from the old tab, **or this is called for the first time**

but also in the implementation, even the first time the scroll offset is set using an animation.

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    scrollState.animateScrollTo(
        calculatedOffset,
        animationSpec = ScrollableTabRowScrollSpec
    )
}
```

And the `ScrollableTabRow` class does not expose a way to control this behaviour.

Comment: So you're saying this is on purpose.... Weird decision

Comment: @m.reiter It seems they did not expose a way to have control over how the scroll is initially set, sadly.